# How to identify your graphics card

Tags: graphics-card

Has powered by ATI   CEFC and CT-ARP128B1-32M who makes it and amount of memory

Comment: For me this isn't a duplicate since the poster here is also asking for the manufacturer.

Comment: Google says it's this - https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ATI-ARP128B1-32M-Rage-128Pro-32MB-AGP-Bus-4x-PC-Graphic-Card-Video-Graphics-Card-/282545727754 - at *least* a decade old, 32MB RAM, won't fit any computer built in the last 10 years.

Answer (score 5):

[GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-gpu-z/)
will tell you everything you want to know:

[image]

Comment: I don't know who makes it

Comment: @ChristopherHostage: For me, the Lookup button took me straight to the manufacturer of my GPU.